# SQL Server 2005 Alter Full text catalog not populating indexes

Tags: sql-server-2005, indexing, fulltext-index

Hi I am rebuilding a full text catalog as follows:

```
ALTER FULLTEXT CATALOG myCatalog REBUILD
```

It is not populating my indexes. When i use the `FULLTEXTCATALOGPROPERTY` to check the properties I am getting the populating status always as 0 and the itemcount as 0.

If i populate the index(which is a part of the catalog above) directly as follows:

```
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON tableName
Start FULL POPULATION
```

**This works fine**, but I am not able to do it through a catalog rebuild.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.